# Three.js - Adding texture makes it look black

Tags: three.js, geometry

I m making custom 3D Objects using an image. First i take outline from an image and after getting points i create the shape. Then i m using three.js extrude geometry to make it look like 3D Object.

The issue is the texture i m using is showing complete black. I used this code to scale the texture.

```
texture.wrapT = texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
var rx = 1/img.width;
var ry = 1/img.height;
texture.repeat.set(rx,ry);
```

This gives me the result in the image below:
NOTE: I m using GLTF Exporter.

[image]

It is scaling the texture correctly, but i cant set the offset. The image is not arranged properly.
I want to dynamically set the offset as my images will be different every time. I can set the offset manually and achieve the results as show in the image below. But i want this to be dynamic.

NOTE: This is the offset i m setting manually for this image to achieve results.

```
texture.offset.set(0.188,0.934);
```

[image]

I really need help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do but ...

`texture.repeat` set how many times a texture repeats so `texture.repeat.set(2,3)` means repeat twice across and three times down. That means your code `texture.repeat.set(1 / img.width, 1 / img.height)` will *expand* the texture so that only 1 pixel is visible.

```
repeat.set(2, 3);
```

repeats 2 across 3 down

```
repeat.set(1/2, 1/3);
```

repeats 0.5 across .33 down or in other words show half the texture across and 1/3 of the texture down

`offset` moves the texture where

- 1 = move it 100% to the left (if the texture repeats there will be no change at 1 since you've move it 100%)
- 0.5 = move it 50% to the left
- 0.25 = move it 25% to the left
- -0.10 = move it -10% to the right

If you want to move it in pixels this is where you'd use img.width

- 1/img.width = move it one pixel left

See the example at the bottom of [this page](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-textures.html)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
  
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);

  const obs = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    const texture = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png');

    // expand the texture so only 40% of stretched across the plane
    texture.repeat.set(0.4, 0.4);
    
    // randomly offset the texture
    texture.offset.set(rand(1), rand(1));
    
    // make it repeat
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
 
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.position.set(rand(-1, 1), rand(-1, 1), 0);
    plane.position.set(rand(-1, 1), rand(-1, 1), 0);
    scene.add(plane);
    obs.push(plane);  // add to our list of obs to rotate
  }
  
  
  
  function rand(min, max) {
    if (max === undefined) {
      max = min;
      min = 0;
    }
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    obs.forEach((obj, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      obj.rotation.z = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```